# Having issues exporting from data lake to Azure SLQ Server DB

Tags: scala, azure, sqoop, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to use Sqoop to export data from my data lake to a table that I setup in Azure SQL Server.  This is all in Azure Data Factory.  The schema of the table matches the schema of the file name, with one exception...I have a column named 'file_name' in the table, which I want to populate from the file itself (this field is not in the raw data).  Here is the code that I tried.

```
sqoop-export 
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://server_name.database.windows.net:1433;username=user_name;password='pass word';database=db_name" 
--table REUTERS_CW 
--export-dir adl://rawdata/corp/file_name.gz 
--input-fields-terminated-by "|"
```

When I run that, I get this error:

```
<console>:10: error: identifier expected but string literal found.
--input-fields-terminated-by "|"
```

There are three things that I'm not sure about.

```
#1) My password actually has spaces in it; I think wrapping that in quotes will fix it.

#2) I'm running this in Scala in Azure Databricks; I'm guessing that's oen way to do it, but I don't know for sure.

#3) I'm not certain about how to copy the data from the file and simultaneously append the file name relative to the data that's supposed to be copied over.
```

I'm following the example from the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-data-transfer-sql-sqoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I get from `sqoop-export` document is that it seems not support compressed files.

You can reference [sqoop-export Syntax](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_3).

**sqoop-export**:

[image]
The `--export-dir` argument and one of `--table` or `--call` are required. These specify the table to populate in the database (or the stored procedure to call), and the directory in HDFS that contains the source data.

**sqoop-import**:

[image]

Hope this helps.